# GWT logs says constructor is undefined though there is no compilation error in the file

Tags: java, gwt-ext

```
I am working on GWT-Ext 2.0.4 .
I have just changed panel class and compiled it and it din't threw any error.
But when i ran the application in Hosted mode i got the following error
```

```
[WARN] Exception thrown into JavaScript
java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: The constructor GrdRowListener() is undefined
```

```
GrdRowListener compiled successfully and there were no compilation errors in the whole project . Also i cleaned the project and build it again but no luck.

Strangely this code works in WEB-MODE and not in hosted mode.

Appreciate your help if you have come across this situation.
```

Answer (score 1):

There are differences between the hosted mode and the web mode.
Basically, in hosted mode the actual Java-Code is executed, in web mode only the compiled Javascript-Code is executed. [Here's an explanation](http://www.vinaytechs.com/2009/09/google-web-toolkit-hosted-vs-web-mode.html).

Now for the (possible) cause of your problem:
Does your GrdRowListener contain the empty constructor? If not - does it contain any non-empty constructors, so that the default (empty) constructor is not available? An empty constructur is sometimes needed for object initializations, e.g. deserialization / bean creation. Pure Javascript should work fine without such a constructor, but Java code won't and that might be the root of your problem. Add the empty constructor to your class and test if it works.